# Should I set a default canonical link sitewide or Is possible to set a custom canonical link automatically in Tumblr?

Tags: wordpress, seo, tumblr, canonical-link

Unfortunately, there's no way (that I know of - I tried below) for me to set a canonical link per Tumblr post so I was thinking of setting the canonical link (sitewide on the Tumblr) to my WordPress homepage - good idea or bad?

I added a content source link to the post and tried adding this to my tumblr theme  but none worked, the link would come out blank...

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Posts}
{block:ContentSource} 
<link rel='canonical' href='{SourceURL}'>
{/block:ContentSource}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:PermalinkPage}
<link rel='canonical' href='{SourceURL}'>
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:ContentSource} 
<link rel='canonical' href='{SourceURL}'>
{/block:ContentSource}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work, it will only render on permalink pages that have pagination. Your posts would need to have pagination for this to work though.

```
{block:PermalinkPagination}
<link rel="canonical" href="{Permalink}" />
{/block:PermalinkPagination}
```

If you don't have pagination in each post, this code would work.

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
<link rel="canonical" href="{Permalink}" />
{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

If you don't want it to be sitewide, this code should also work and will only render on post pages and not on others.

```
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Date}
<link rel="canonical" href="{Permalink}" />
{/block:Date}{/block:PermalinkPage}
```

Comment: thanks but the problem is, I dont want to use the permalink for the canonical link, I want to use the content source link...

Comment: Could you link me to your tumblr? Maybe it's blank because your theme doesn't have the {block:ContentSource} variable.

Comment: it did... but i just tried it and it worked... well this one worked: `{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Posts}
{block:ContentSource} 
<link rel='canonical' href='{SourceURL}'>
{/block:ContentSource}
{/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}`
yes!!! thanks